# A dynamic URL implementation for a RESTful API in Google App Engine

Tags: api, google-app-engine, rest

A client application will send a message using a GET method to http://server/user/USER_ID/history in order to receive a JSON reply containing the usage history of the user. (may it be a list of songs listened to, purchases, etc)

I can get as far as to handling http://server/user/USER_ID/ via the following snippet:

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
        [('/', BrowserTests),
         ('/user/([^/]+)?', UserHandler),
        ], debug=True)
```

Which I consume in UserHandler via:

```
user_id = str(urllib.unquote(resource))
```

And thus I can carry out the work for http://server/user/USER_ID. But how can I go a step further and consume *history*?

I tried looking up on StackOverflow and in the documentation, but I guess I don't know exactly what to ask for to receive an answer.

Comment: Dom Derrien has a great description of implementing an MVC model for creation of a RESTful API in GAE. Please look up his blog for details: http://domderrien.blogspot.com/2009/03/mvc-pattern-and-rest-api-applied-to-gae.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could go with something like this:

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
    ('/user/([^/]+)/([^/]+)', UserHandler),
    ], debug=True)


class UserHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self, user_id, action_to_consume):
    self.response.out.write("Action %s" % action_to_consume)#Should print History
```

Comment: Never ever^100 call `print` inside a WSGI application.

Comment: @Nick nitpicker, spend some +1 instead :P.

Comment: Not a nitpick - the original sample wouldn't have worked. Now I can upvote you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Add a second parameter

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
        [('/', BrowserTests),
         ('/user/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$', UserHandler),
        ], debug=True)

class UserHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, userid, history):
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternately to @Jose and @systempuntoout's answers, if you want a separate handler for each action:

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', BrowserTests),
    ('/user/([^/]+)', UserHandler),
    ('/user/([^/]+)/history', HistoryHandler),
], debug=True)

class UserHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self, userid):
    pass

class HistoryHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self, userid):
    pass
```